# elementary complex functions theory question

Tags: complex-analysis

I was asked to prove te following:

Given a complex function $f$ holomorphic in the punctured disk centered in $z$ with radius $r$, $D'(z,r)$, if $z$ is an isolated singularity of $f$ and $\lim_{w\rightarrow z} f(z)= \infty$, then there exists a positive integer $N$ and complex numbers $\left (c_n \right)_{n\geqslant -N}$ such that $c_{-N} \neq 0$ and $f(w)= \sum_{n=-N}^{\infty} c_n(w-z)^n$ for $w \in D'(z,r)$. Also prove that $N$ is uniquely determined by $f$. As a hint was given: Prove that there exists a $\rho \in (0,r)$ for which the formula holds (I can do that part) and conclude, because, if a complex function $g$ is holomorphic in an open and connected subset $V$ of $\mathbb{C}$ and the set of zero's of $g$ has a limit point in $V$, then $g$ is constant in $V$ (I cannot deduct appropriately from the latter fact). Also, I don't see how to prove that $N$ is unique. Any thoughts?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Google "Laurent Series"